# Uncaught TypeError: undefined is not a function for request() in Titanium

Tags: javascript, android, titanium

I have a problem with 1 of my functions.
in app.js ia have th following:

```
//Including all functions
Ti.include('functions.js');

//Including the login screen
Ti.include('login.js');

//Including the register screen
Ti.include('register.js');
```

So all the functions are above the other files that could call a function.

In login.js I have the following code:

```
//'login' is the type
var request = request('login', loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value));
        Ti.API.info('request: ' + request);
        if(request == true) {
            alert('You are loggedin');
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong');
        }
```

The request function looks like this:

```
function request(type, username, password) {
    //Database connection
    var db = Ti.Network.createHTTPClient();
    db.open('POST', 'http://myip/mobile_app/');

    Ti.API.info('type: ' + type);
    Ti.API.info('username: ' + username);
    Ti.API.info('password: ' + password);

    //If variables has been send
    db.onload = function() {
        var answer = this.responseText;
        Ti.API.info('type answer: ' + typeof this.responseText);
        if(answer == 'true') {
           Ti.API.info('TEST');
           return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    };

    //Variables to send
    db.send({
        type: type,
        username: username,
        password: md5(password) 
    });

    //If there is an error
    db.onerror = function(e) {
        Ti.API.info('error: ' + JSON.stringify(e));
    };
}
```

I know that this.responseText returns true and that the `function md5()` works aswell.
I know this because I also tested login.js when the code is like:

```
Ti.API.info('request: ' + request('login', loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value)));
        if(request('login', loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value)) == true) {
            alert('You are loggedin');
        } else {
            alert('Something went wrong');
        }
```

The above also returns that `function request()` is `undefined`

So as soon as try to login I get the following error:
[image]

So my question is how can resolve the error?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question got answered here: http://developer.appcelerator.com/question/175412/function-not-returning-anything#280011

**Edit:**
In User.js:

```
function request(type, username, password, callback) {
    db.onload = function() {
        Ti.API.info('type antwoord: ' + typeof this.responseText);
        callback( this.responseText );
    };
}

exports.login = function(username, password, callback) {
    request('login', username, password, callback);
};
```

and in login.js:

```
// last parameter is the callback function
User.login(loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value), function(response){
    Ti.API.info('login response: ' + response)
});
```

now i get true or false as `response`.

Comment: Please post the fix and not just the link.

Answer (score 2):

I think the issue is that you redefine variable `request` to the return value of `function request`. You request function does not return anything. Therefore it returns `undefined`.

Now that you set `request` to `undefined`. You cannot use `request()` anymore, because you overwrote it.

Attempting to call an undefined value as a function, results in undefined is not a function

See demonstration: http://repl.it/UXE/1

Answer (score 1):

Indeed, @Gabs00 is right when he says that you're redefining your request variable.

But the real question is **how could you have avoid this problem** ?

And the answer is in the way you're coding. By using **Ti.include**, you're not using the best practices recommended by Titanium.

Instead, you should do something like this :

In a file **models/User.js** :

```
exports.request = function(type, username, password) {
    // Your code here
};
```

Then, instead of writing (in your **app.js** file) :

```
Ti.include('functions.js');
var request = request('login', loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value));
```

You'll have :

```
var User = require('models/User');
User.request('login', loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value));
```

But even with this code, it's sot satisfying enough...
What you should probably try is to declare as many functions as your requests. Even if your code is common for your 2 requests for now, I can assure you that it won't be that way very long.

Thus, there is the final code I recommend :

In your **models/User.js** file :

```
function request(type, username, password) {
    // Your code
};
exports.login = function(username, password) {
    request('login', username, password);
};
exports.register = function(username, password) {
    request('register', username, password);
};
```

The cool thing with this code is that your **request** method is totally protected: the only code which can access this function is the one written in your **models/User.js** file. For the others, it's like this function doesn't even exist.

In you **app.js** file :

```
var User = require('models/User');
User.login(loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value));
```

I think it's more readable this way, don't you?

If you want more information about this pattern, you should probably read these articles:

- [CommonJS modules](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/CommonJS+Modules+in+Titanium)
- [Titanium best practices](https://wiki.appcelerator.org/display/guides2/Coding+Best+Practices#CodingBestPractices-AppArchitectureRecommendations)

As you'll see, you should reuse this pattern for your windows too (your **Ti.include('login.js');** and **Ti.include('register.js');**)

Comment: First I want to thank you for your answer and explanation. I have changed some things like you said with the models etc. I also changed my `function request()` like this: `db.onload = function() {         Ti.API.info('type antwoord: ' + typeof this.responseText);         return this.responseText;     };` after is did this I tested a few things in login.js like this: `Ti.API.info('login response: ' + User.login(loginUsernameInput.value, md5(loginPasswordInput.value)));` this still returned: `login response: undefined` which imo should return `true` or `false`?

Comment: so am I wrong at this point or is something else going wrong. I would really like to know this because I need this login / register.

Comment: Sorry, I haven't been notified of your question. The problem is that your **responseText** isn't defined yet. It will be asynchronously set when the answer of your HTTP request will come back. Cf. [the doc](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/latest/#!/api/Titanium.Network.HTTPClient) for more info (search for *Asynchronous vs. Synchronous HTTP Requests*). What you need to do is defined the **onload** callback (cf. the same doc). In case of error, you should definitely define the **onerror** callback too.